# How to access user defined function from another file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I defined a service class to get user's location and I want to call that function in my LandingPage.
I am getting function not defined for class error. Am I using it in the wrong way?

**LocationService.dart**

```
  String location;
  Position _currentPosition;

  _getCurrentLocation(){
    //...
  }

}
```

**LandingPage.dart**

```
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LocationService _locationService = LocationService();
    _locationService._getCurrentLocation();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: SignInPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By prefixing your `getCurrentLocation` method with an `underscore(_)`, it means you are making that method only accessible inside the `class` it belongs too.

To be able to use the `method` in other parts of your program, remove the `underscore(_)`.

Check the code below:

```
 String location;
  Position _currentPosition;

  // remove the underscore and make it accessible in other parts of your code
  getCurrentLocation(){
    //...
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer so others can see the relevance @user10083

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, private properties and functions are declared by a preceding `_` sign. So your function `_getCurrentLocation` is a private function.

That makes it only accessible within it's own class, and not outside of it.

If you rename your method to `getCurrentLocation` it should work.
See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help!